# I/O Error: Sistema de archivos de solo lectura en SSD (XUBUNTU)

Tags: linux

Mi problema radica de que a veces el sistema completo se monta en solo lectura, sobre todo cuando utilizo operaciones de root (apt-get, ssh e incluso cuando el qBitorrent esta chequeando los archivos descargados), cuando trato de remontar la unidad me sale esto:

> ---
>
> user@group:~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw / [sudo] password for user:
>
> sudo:no es posible abrir /var/lib/sudo/user/1: No existe el archivo o
>
> el directorio montar: no se puede remontar dispositivo de bloques
>
> /dev/sda1 como sólo lectura, está protegido contra escritura
>
> ---

Luego de esto, cualquier operación que haga, así sea en xfce o nautilus, no me la permite por que aparecen todos los iconos con un candado, y en la sección de permisos en la información del archivo sale que el propietario es root.

> Anexo la información de mi sistema:
>
> S.O = Xubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS)
>
> CPU = Intel Core i5 M460
>
> SSD = KINGSTON SV300S37A120G (120GB)
>
> GPU = nVidia GeForce m310

Comment: Hola @jesteven, bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Puede que le interese leer esto: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour. Es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada porque [no se encuentra dentro del alcance](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), no se lo tome a mal.

Comment: @toledano si se encuentra dentro del alcance. ver aquí http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/166/25